# In flutter, how to fix drawer exceed margin

Tags: flutter, drawer

**Edit**: This error only happen in Xioami Redmi Note 7 (Android version 10), work perfectly on other device like samsaung (Android version 13).

**Edit**: I reproduced again. I found this happen when pop back to drawer from drawer navigation.
(Eg: Go to notification screen from drawer navigation stack and pop back).

I found an issue with the flutter drawer while implementing UI.
Please see below image. Drawer header exceed a white margin that I except. But that exceed margin not always happen every time although I reproduce by opening drawer again and again. It only happen in usual when not expected. What is happen and how to fix?
I test this with only in debug mode.

```
DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const FlutterLogo(
                  size: largeIconSize,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'LA PYAE TEST',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '09500007958',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5?.copyWith(
                            fontSize: textRegular2X,
                          ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Balance: 0 MMK',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5?.copyWith(
                            fontSize: textRegular,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

**Edit**
here is my `Drawer`  body completely ,

```
Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          /// TODO Bind data
          DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const FlutterLogo(
                  size: largeIconSize,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'LA PYAE TEST',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '09500007958',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5?.copyWith(
                            fontSize: textRegular2X,
                          ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Balance: 0 MMK',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5?.copyWith(
                            fontSize: textRegular,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, notificationRoute);
            },
            leading: const Icon(
              Icons.notifications_none_outlined,
              size: 30,
            ),
            title: const Text(NOTIFICATION),
          ),
          const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.settings_outlined,
              size: 30,
            ),
            title: Text(APP_SETTING),
          ),
          const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.location_on_outlined,
              size: 30,
            ),
            title: Text(LOCATIONS),
          ),
          const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.question_mark_outlined,
              size: 30,
            ),
            title: Text(ABOUT),
          ),
          const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.logout_outlined,
              size: 30,
            ),
            title: Text(LOG_OUT),
          ),
          const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.share,
              size: 30,
            ),
            title: Text(SHARE_APP),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: please try to add your drawer code also your header working correct in my side no white space add your `Drawer` code

Comment: This error only happen in Xioami Redmi Note 7 (Android version 10), work perfectly on other device like samsaung (Android version 13).

Answer (score 0):

add

```dart
padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

to drawer header widget

Comment: Did you mean add ```Drawer``` inside to the ```Padding``` widget? Or something... Please answer me detail.

Comment: DrawerHeader widget.

Comment: No. Although I add ```Padding``` inside ```DrawerHeader```. Nothing change happen and this issue still happen,

Comment: This is not happen due to UI widget. Only happen in that phone. Not become with other phone. so confused.